# Include and ThenInclude with IQueryable<T> in C# . NET Core

Tags: c#, database, linq, .net-core, iqueryable

Imagine I have the followings tables in my DataBase:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int IdA { get; set; }
    public string DesA { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassesB { get; set; }

}
public class ClassB
{
    public int IdB { get; set; }
    public string DesB { get; set; }

    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClassD> ClassesD { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public int IdC { get; set; }
    public string DesC { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassesB { get; set; }
}
public class ClassD
{
    public int IdD { get; set; }
    public string DesD { get; set; }

    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}
```

I want know to make a query with includes to my DB.

I have been doing like that, first I get the `IQueryable<ClassA>` from the DBContext. After that I set the list of includes that i want in the query
`List<string> includes = new List<string> { "ClassesB.ClassC", "ClassesB.ClassesD" };`

And use a extension method to set the includes of a generic IQueryable.

```
public static IQueryable<T> BuildQuery(this IQueryable<T> query, List<string> includes)
{         
    foreach (var operation in includes)
        query = query.Include(operation);

    return query;
}
```

The code works, but i don't want to use a list of string to make the includes of the querys.

If I modify the extension to not be generic, I can do that:

```
public static IQueryable<ClassA> BuildQuery(this IQueryable<ClassA> query)
{
    query.Include(x => x.ClassesB).ThenInclude(x => x.ClassC);
    query.Include(x => x.ClassesB).ThenInclude(x => x.ClassesD);

    return query;
}
```

But i don't know how to do that as a `IQueryable<T>` and pass the .Include/.ThenInclude Expressions as a parameter.

I don't need the method to be static, it doesn't mind, but I want to simulate the Include/ThenInclude from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions library with something like this...

```
 public static IQueryable<T> BuildQuery(this IQueryable<T> query, List<IncludesClass> includesItem)
{
    foreach (var operation in includesItem)
        query = query.Include(operation.Include).ThenInclude(operation.ThenInclude);

    return query;
}
```

Any ideas??

Thank you!

--------- UPDATE ---------

I need to do that way because i don't have access to the IQueryable, it's autogenerated from Criterias

```
public IEnumerable<T> Matches<T>(ICriteria<T> criteria,List<string> includes)
        where T : class
    {
        var query = criteria.BuildQuery(_context.Set<T>(), includes); 
        //Do more things...

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't query and Include up everything you need with one Query ?

Comment: I can't do that, I simplified the example, but the IQueryable is generated from another generic method. And I need that the list of includes as a property to re-use form multiples querys

Comment: Why you need `Includes` somewhere in intermediate queries? It is needed only before `ToList()` call, when you know which relations are needed for result.

Comment: I make an update to the question trying to explain better why i don't have access to the IQueryable and need to do that way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
        public IQueryable<T> BuildQuery<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class
        {
            var query = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
            return
                includes.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }
```

and then when you want to use it:

```
myQueryBulder.BuildQuery<ClassA>(include=>include.ClassesB).Where(x=>x.IdA == 1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, something with the Aggregate will works with .Include, buy any idea of how to do for the .ThenInclude?

Comment: Just continue to include: myQueryBulder.BuildQuery<ClassA>(include=>include.ClassesB, include=>include.ClassC).Where(x=>x.IdA == 1)

Comment: That doen't works because include is type of ClassA (T), and doen't have the ClassC property, it's only in ClassB and a .ThenInclude is needed, another include doesn't works

Comment: Will this work: myQueryBulder.BuildQuery<ClassA>(include=>include.ClassesB.ClassC).Where(x=>x.IdA == 1)